# word wrap after specific width

Tags: css

hi
i have container of width 135px when dynamic labeles are displayed words are overflow instead of auto word wrap so let me know what may be solution for this.

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

or

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```